# Error with undefined variables while looping over a query

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I have an error while looping over a query using `cfloop`.

When I use a `cfdump` on the query (inside the loop, mind you), I can see all the data just fine.  But when I try to get the value of each variable as you normally do in `cfloop`, I get a message that says they are undefined.  I then changed each variable to reference the query specifically, and now the problem is that the variable is undefined in the query.  Here's the code:

```
<cffunction name="writeCourses">
<cfargument name="recordset" required="yes" type="query">
     <cfif recordset.RecordCount NEQ 0>
         <cfset temp = "">  
         <cfoutput>
         <cfloop query="recordset">     
         <!--- <cfdump var="#recordset#"> <cfabort/> --->  

            <cfset temp = temp & "<strong>#recordset.courseType# #recordset.courseNum# ">
            <cfif isDefined("recordset.courseTHM") AND recordset.courseTHM EQ 1>
                <cfset temp = temp & "(#left(recordset.courseNum,3)#4) ">
            </cfif>
            <cfif isDefined("recordset.courseName")>
                <cfset temp = temp & "#recordset.courseName# </strong><br>">
            </cfif>
            <cfset temp = temp & "#recordset.courseDESC#<br>">
            <cfset temp = temp & "#recordset.courseHours#<br><br>">
        </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
     <cfelse>
        <cfset temp = "">
     </cfif>
 <cfreturn temp>
</cffunction>
```

So as you can see, each variable is enclosed in `##` tags.  Originally none of them were proceeded by `recordset.` but they were still undefined.  And when I uncomment the `cfdump` and `cfabort` tags, those work fine and I can see the `recordset` query with all the data as it should be.

Every other time I have used `cfloop` with a query it works as expected.  Also, I did not write this code, I am having to modify it (the original author no longer works here).

Here's an example of the `recordset` dump:

[image]

The error message:
Detail:         [empty string]
ErrNumber:       0
Message:          Element COURSETYPE is undefined in RECORDSET.
Resolvedname:      RECORDSET

The error line is:

```
   <cfset temp = temp & "<strong>#recordset.courseType# #recordset.courseNum# ">   
   <cfif isDefined("recordset.courseTHM") AND recordset.courseTHM EQ 1>
   <cfset temp = temp & "(#left(recordset.courseNum,3)#4) ">
   </cfif>
   <cfif isDefined("recordset.courseName")>
   <cfset temp = temp & "#recordset.courseName# </strong><br>">
   </cfif>
```

That's all one line :/

The stored procedure/function calling the above:

```
<cffunction name="getCoursesByDept">
<cfargument name="deptCode" required="yes" type="string">
<CFSTOREDPROC procedure="dbo.GetCourses"     datasource="WebCatalog">
    <CFPROCPARAM type="IN" dbvarname="@deptCode" value="#deptCode#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR">
    <CFPROCRESULT name="result">
</CFSTOREDPROC>
<cfinvoke method="writeCourses" recordset="#result#" returnvariable="output">
<cfreturn output>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Could you show us the `<cfdump>` output (or at least a portion of it showing the recordset)?

Comment: Adding some examples now.

Comment: Which variable and line is the error pointing too?  Can you share the actual error message?

Comment: Here's the first part:
Detail
[empty string] |

ErrNumber  0 |

Message  Element COURSETYPE is undefined in RECORDSET. |

Resolvedname  RECORDSET |. 

  
  If I just have `#courseType` instead of `#recordset.courseType#` I just have a message saying that COURSETYPE is undefined.

Comment: Assuming `temp` was defined somewhere earlier. Perhaps with a `<cfparam name="temp" default="">` or a `<cfset temp = "">`?

Comment: Oh, and the error message is on the line where `coursetype` is first used, with an id of CF_DOTRESOLVER

Edit:  Chester, yeah the line before the `<cfoutput>` has `<cfset temp = "">`

Comment: @mAlenius: Please edit your question to include this information. Comments are impermanent and, as you can see, don't allow for much in the way of formatting.

Comment: Thanks, should have just done that in the beginning.

Comment: Are you getting the error on the first iteration of the loop? I don't see anything wrong with your code and you are correct; you should not need to specify `recordset.` for your variables in this case.  Could you also show us your `<cfquery>` that is defining the recordset?

Comment: I've done it without `recordset`, the variables are still undefined.  So are you suggesting that I put in checks against null values (in case the first pass is bugged)?

Comment: You should not need to do that. Even if the value is NULL, the variable would still be defined (just empty in ColdFusion).  I'm not sure what is happening.  Your code looks okay. Can you share your `<cfquery>` code that defines recordset?

Comment: is it possible recordset is a reserved word? The code looks fine to me otherwise.

Comment: It's the result of a stored procedure, which has worked fine in other places. I looked at the `cfinvoke` that calls the method containing the above code, it seems to pass `recordset` just fine.  Don't really want to post the whole storedproc, but it basically pulls rows where the type is equal to the passed parameter (a string).

Comment: @MattBusche It might be, will look into it. Currently declared as the only parameter to the function this code is contained in...

Comment: Just a shot in the dark .. 1) Does the procedure *always* return a resultset? 2) Also, if there is a cfc involved, could it be a threading problem? Could you post the function code- and the `cfinvoke` call?

Comment: I just mocked up some code and it's not a reserved word. If your query didn't have results it wouldn't get to your `<cfset>`, so there's something not posted that's going wrong

Comment: @mAlenius can you post the storedproc minus the arguments you're passing in?

Comment: @Leigh  1) Yes, it does.  If it can't find anything it returns a query containing an error message (i.e. no course found)   2)There is no cfc, the function call and stored procedure call is all in one .cfm file.

Comment: Updated OP.  Now contains full function surrounding the loop, as well as the stored proc call for the query, and the function call where the query is passed.  Done for the day and have evening classes, so I won't be able to pull actual code samples if necessary.

Comment: after your `<cfargument>` can you do `<cfset var recordset = arguments.recordset>`

Comment: As a matter of course, is there a reason that the stored proc is returning blank rows?  Rows 4 to 12 have no data.

Comment: @Chester Looks like he just collapsed those rows when he took his screenshot

Comment: @mAlenius - Re *..returns a query containing an error message* That means the course columns do not always exist in the resultset, which is exactly what the error message is reporting. The first line of code uses those columns without verifying they exist first. As an side, the error message should really be generated in CF, not inside the procedure. The procedure's job is just to return data. Also, you really need to localize the function variables `result`, `output`, `temp`, etectera. Lack of `var` scoping can create problems even within same page if you reuse variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be failure to scope.  Here are your first 4 lines:

```
<cffunction name="writeCourses">
<cfargument name="recordset" required="yes" type="query">
 <cfif recordset.RecordCount NEQ 0>
     <cfset temp = "">
```

Try it like this:

```
<cffunction name="writeCourses">
<cfargument name="recordset" required="yes" type="query">
<cfset var temp = "">  
<cfif arguments.recordset.RecordCount NEQ 0>
```

The differences are the use of the var keyword for your local variable temp, and adding the arguments scope to the recordset variable.

Comment: That did the trick; thanks :)  I also added isDefined checks for each variable, that might have helped, as well.

Comment: @mAlenius don't use `isDefined()` use `structKeyExists(structure,value)` instead

Answer (score 0):

(In addition to Dan's comments ...)

> If [the procedure] can't find anything it returns a query containing
>   an error message (i.e. no course found)

Then that means the `COURSETYPE` column does not always exist in the `resultset`, which is exactly what the error message is reporting. If the procedure returns *any* result, regardless of the contents, the code inside the `cfif` block will execute. Since the first line of code uses that column, without verifying it exists, it would cause the exact error you are seeing.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, you really need to localize the function variables `result`, `output`, `temp`, etectera. Lack of `var` scoping can create problems, even within same page, if you reuse variable names. As @Dan suggested you should fully scope all variables - in particular, the function `arguments`.

(As an aside, I understand you are modifying existing code, but the error message should really be handled in CF, *not* inside the procedure. The procedure's job is just to return data. The CF code should check the recordCount and take the appropriate action if no records are found.)

Comment: The stored procedure just returns an empty query if nothing is found; I misread it initially.

Comment: Hm.. that does not jive with the error you described ;-) But glad it is working now.